# Average Formula

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am creating a Marks sheet for school which code is below:

```py
Sub1 = input ('Enter Marks of English: ')
Sub2 = input ('Enter Marks of Urdu: ')
Sub3 = input ('Enter Marks of Science: ')
Sub4 = input ('Enter Marks of Maths: ')
Sub5 = input ('Enter Marks of Islamiat: ')
avg = (Sub1+Sub2+Sub3+Sub4+Sub5)
Sub1 = int(Sub1)
Sub2 = int(Sub2)
Sub3 = int(Sub3)
Sub4 = int(Sub4)
Sub5 = int(Sub5)
if avg >90 or (avg <80):
    print("Grade: A")
elif avg > 79 or (avg < 61):
    print("Grade: B")
elif avg > 60 or (avg < 40):
    print("Grade: C")
elif avg > 40 or (avg < 39):
    print("Grade: D")
else:
    print("Grade: F")
```

However getting error when taking average as follow

```
TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-68aee6e8df0f> in <module>
     12 Sub5 = int(Sub5)
     13
---> 14 if avg >90 or (avg <80):
     15     print("Grade: A")
     16 elif avg > 79 or (avg < 61):
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Please help to fix tomorrow have to submit my assignment.

Comment: Do the `avg()` after you `int`ed the inputs (which are strings). And also, you probably want to divide it by 5 to get the average and not the sum.

Comment: I think your logic is a bit wonky. You say a person should get an A if their score is above 90 or less than 80 -- so a score of 4 is an A?

Answer (score 1):

When you read user input your variables are `str`. So, you need to conver your Subn variables to int before adding. Replace:

```
avg = (Sub1+Sub2+Sub3+Sub4+Sub5)
Sub1 = int(Sub1)
Sub2 = int(Sub2)
Sub3 = int(Sub3)
Sub4 = int(Sub4)
Sub5 = int(Sub5)
```

for

```
Sub1 = int(Sub1)
Sub2 = int(Sub2)
Sub3 = int(Sub3)
Sub4 = int(Sub4)
Sub5 = int(Sub5)
avg = (Sub1+Sub2+Sub3+Sub4+Sub5)
```

Comment: you did it man :-) only one line give a lot issues, appreciated your help thanks alot

Comment: In python, if you add two strings it will join them. For example, if you have first_name = 'Abid' and last_name 'Hussain', first_name + last_name will returns 'AbidHussain'. So, even if your user input is a number, python will assume it's a string. That's why you need to convert for INT before doing the math. Also, be aware that you are not calculating an average; you must divide by 5 then

Answer (score 0):

You have code to convert the inputs from strings to ints, which is necessary to avoid a TypeError here. But you are calculating `avg` before this conversion, so `avg` is a string. The solution is to move the line

```py
avg = (Sub1+Sub2+Sub3+Sub4+Sub5)
```

to after you have converted these variables into ints.

Note also that this formula gives the sum, not the average.